# How to build object after serialize in Django

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I am serializing the instance of a model in the following way.

```
serialized_object = serializers.serialize ('json', [track,])
```

output

```
   [{"model": "blog.track", "pk": null, "fields": {"album": null, "name": "Song 1", "lyrics": "", "song": "Z.mp3", "url_download": null, "length": "00:00:12"}}]
```

Then I save the serialized object, so that at the end of some tasks I can save it in the database. My question is how do I re-build the instance of the model from the serialized model. And how can I get the fields of the serialized model in the view?

Investigating a little more and reading the Django documentation that can be deserialized and saved in this way

```
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", serialized_object):
    print(obj.name)
    obj.save ()
```

however I would like to obtain the values of that object but when trying it the following error occurs

```
AttributeError: 'DeserializedObject' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/): _The Django object itself can be inspected as `deserialized_object.object`. If fields in the serialized data do not exist on a model, a `DeserializationError` will be raised unless the `ignorenonexistent` argument is passed in as True_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because the documentation indicates that your object is wrapped in a DeserializedObject, so make the following change.

```
print (obj.object.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django rest framework then you dont need to convert back to object. you can use `create` or `update` method on serializer class as mentioned [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) to create or update in db